# wordpress remove post categories from url

Tags: wordpress, url, permalinks

i have set the permalinks to this

```
> /%postname%/
```

however in the url, if the post has a category, it still shows in the url

Is it possible to change make the change so that this url:

> http://www.website.com.au/post-category/post-name/

to this

> http://www.website.com.au/post-name/

htaccess looks like this

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: I think this should work.
Can you past your .htaccess file code in question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Previous plugin will remove category word from URL.. if you want to remove category also try below plugin: 
http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/remove-parents/

Answer (score 2):

Install no category base plugin: http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-no-category-base/

Comment: no good. This takes away the folder 'category' from the url. ts a actual category for posts that I want to remove, not the base name.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using the Yoast plugin you can go to advanced > permalinks > Strip the category base from the category URL.

Alternatively I wrote a blog post on how to strip the category url without a plugin below.

http://jonnyjordan.com/blog/how-to-remove-category-from-your-urls-in-wordpress/